# Send PHP mails so mails stack as one conversation in inbox or imitate a reply

Tags: php, email, header

I have a chat system were notifications about the chat are send to the emailadreses which are involved. I would like to imitate the effect of conversation stacking in the receiver's inbox. Is there a way to do this?

I tried:

```
$headers = [
    'Thread-Topic' => $subject
];
wp_mail( 'test@test.com', $subject, $content, $headers);
```

and

```
wp_mail( 'test@test.com', 'RE: '.$subject, $content );
```

and

```
$headers = [
    'Message-ID' => 'custommailsystem'
];
wp_mail( 'test@test.com', $subject, $content, $headers);
```

Sending emails works, but they do not stack as one conversation in the receiver's inbox. They show up as separate mails, like this:

[image: unstacked emails]

To make sure the receiver gets the emails in a organised way, I want emails to stack like this in the receiver's inbox:

[image: stacked emails by conversation]

Which headers are used to achieve the stacking in the mail? What determines in which conversation an email belongs?

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Isn't a conversation a series of replies all from a single, original email?  It's not made up of several unique emails from a person to another person - it's an email from one person that has been replied to back and forth, right?  Besides that, leave a person's inbox organization up to their preference - they should be able to choose if they want things in conversation/stacked view or not.

Comment: But how to imitate a conversation using PHP mail? I want to use this feature for a website that has a chat based system, and sends the conversation out to the emails of the people involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supose you are sending mails from an emailaddress called `mycustommail@system.com`

To imitate a reply to a mail, or stacking a conversation per subject. Set the `In-Reply-To` to a the `Message-ID` of the email you want to 'reply' to. The presence of `In-Reply-To` and References headers indicate that the message is a reply to a previous message. [Read more on understanding email headers](https://wesmorgan.blogspot.com/2012/07/understanding-email-headers-part-ii.html).

Emails with the same subject (or `RE:` in front) will stack accordingly.